wh-word and adjunction (Russian as an example)
I am reading The Syntax of Russian by John Frederick Bailyn. He takes the wh-word который to be of category AP/NP. Also he assumes that adjuncts operates at the level of XP, not X-bar.
Given that, if a PP о друге (about a friend) is understood to be a complement (which it is), then we will have an incorrect instance of a relative clause:
**книга, которую он написал о друге* (the book he wrote about a friend)

But this is a good sentence which leads me to think that PP is actually dominated by VP
If a PP под названием Х (titled as X) is an adjunct, we should have a correct sentence as
*Книга, которую я положил под названием Х на стол* (the book that I put titled X on the table)

As a Russian native speaker, I find it strange. It can be argued, however, that this PP is actually a complement and so my intuition is correct.
There is another example, though, a PP с твердым переплетом (hard cover) which acts as a modifier, so we should get
*Книга, которую я положил с твердым перелетом на стол* (the book that I put hard-cover on the table)

Again, it does not sound right.
So the question is: is what I have written actually correct? If so, how can one account for a sentence like the following which was found in a corpus? What do we do about the second PP под названием ХХХ?
*книга, которую мне подарили про ВТО под названием ХХХ* (the book that I was gifted about WTO titled XXX)

